# Can´t access Joomla admin panel with administrator account

Tags: joomla, administrator

This problem started with me needing to add a module to my frontpage so only guests will see it, after they login the module disappears. So I read this [tutorial](http://brian.teeman.net/tips-and-tricks/the-guest-user-group-hiding-menu-items-and-modules.html) :

Basically says to do this..

Create a Guest Group in the User Manager
Add a new Guest Viewing Access Level
Change the default guest group in the User Manager options

And it works! But the problem now is when I login with my administrator account on admin panel, i get only 3 icons from Zoo component, no admin bar menu, nothing! And if try to login to the admin panel with a default user account I get the same thing! I´m now in the joomla database to try and see if I can delete the user group I created before and maybe it works?

I cannot lose the content of the website, it´s important! Please help. I´m the latest version of joomla.

Thanks very much

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Bobby Jack: I do you not agree with you! You should close all Joomla related questions!

Comment: @Arnaud: I don't understand your point. Maybe there's some sarcasm ther ethat's difficult to detect :-) My argument would be that this question is not a programming question, so it should be closed. A programming question related to Joomla, however, would be quite welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your files and database and set your website in offline mode: edit your configuration.php file and set:

```
public $offline = '1';
```

After that, you can try your solution.